# How to convert this code VB to javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have this code in VB and I need to convert it to JavaScript.

```
text_exit &= Chr(y And & HFFS)
```

I managed to translate all the rest of the code, but this line did not succeed.
I don't understand the arguments, but `y` is a number previously obtained.

Comment: Should `& HFFS` be `&HFFS`?  That at least makes sense if `y` is an integer type. `&H` is the prefix for hexadecimal notation.  The `S` is called a type literal character signifying that the type is "Short Integer" (`Int16`).  So  `&HFFS` equals 255.

Comment: "...did not succeed:" please read https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please show your attempt, and describe how it differs from the result you expected. Show expected output. You can edit to bring it up to the format & type of Q that SO is designed to handle. Good luck.

Comment: As a note for anybody coming in from the JS side, `And` in VB is bitwise.  This code in VB is getting the low byte from y by masking and converting it from an integer to a character.

Answer (score -1):

```
text_exit &= String.fromCharCode( y && HFFS )
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. the code does not recognize this HFFS and I have no idea what that term is.

Comment: Did not work. The javascript code does not recognize the term HFFS and returns an error. I'm trying to look for what it is but I can't find anything that explains what it is

Comment: I did not find in JAVA, C# and VB i found some things but nothing that helped me yet

Comment: Code only posts are frowned upon as SO  Answers, though they are welcomed in the comments section. For long term value, please add an explanation so that future visitors can learn & quickly determine if they can apply it to their own coding issues. Quality answers are more likely to be upvoted, as they are more helpful, and they keep value high of SO as a platform. Consider editing to highlight important portions of your solution, or explaining parts that may not be obvious to users unaccustomed to this particular code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Javascript, but I question whether `&&` is correct.  C-derived syntax usually uses that for a logical "and", but the VB is doing a bitwise "and".